# Writing a regular expression to list IPv4 addresses found in a docker network

Tags: linux, bash, grep, docker

Hello while inspecting the characteristics of a docker network with the command `docker network inspect network59` , I noticed the precence of ipv4 address and I would like to write a regular expression to list the IPv4 addresses found specifically  in the result of this command.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) example input and ii) expected output. Do you want every single case of 4 sets of 1-3 digits separated by `.`? Are there any other criteria? Can you have more than one per line? Can an IP be spread across multiple lines? What kind of tool will you be using? What regular expression language can it consume? Is this for GNU grep? Something else?

Comment: Matching an IPv4 address with a regex should be a rather straightforward, though tedious exercise. Is there some part of it in particular that's causing you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about regex but `jq` might be able to help.
You can pass in the jsonpath to whatever you want in the single quotes.

Below command works for a json like below to extract the Gateway-

```
$ docker network inspect bridge | jq -r '.[0].IPAM.Config[0].Gateway'
172.17.0.1
```

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "f6daefc7df41c4ddb9c1620b57986b9b65bb4c9afa939af2b6baa6ef7be0f23f",
        "Created": "2023-11-14T10:31:54.319592088Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1454"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Regexp::Common` perl module has a library of regular expressions to match a number of common things including IPv4 addresses in quad-decimal notations:

```
docker... | perl -MRegexp::Common=net -lne 'print for m{$RE{net}{IPv4}}g'
```

Note that it will find `231.2.3.45` inside `v1231.2.3.456.7` as it is a valid IPv4 address. Adding some context to that IP address might help. For instance you could constrain it to mandate that the IP address be preceded by `"` or whitespace only and followed by `"`, whitespace or `/` only with:

```
docker... | perl -MRegexp::Common=net -lne '
   print for m{(?<=["\s])$RE{net}{IPv4}(?=["\s/])}g'
```

To report on JSON strings whose value looks like an IPv4 address in dotted-quad-decimal format:

```
docker... | jq -r '
  ..|strings|select(test("^\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{1,3}){3}\\z"))'
```

(not as strict a match as `Regexp::Common` one as it will accept `999.888.777.666` for instance).